# When is git's refs/remotes/origin filled with branch files?

Tags: git

After cloning a repository with several branches on the server, I noticed the local `.git/refs/remotes/origin` directory only contains a file `HEAD` but not the branch files (as I expected).

When I do a `git branch -r` or a `git branch -a` all remote branches are listed.

When are the branch files unter `refs/remotes/origin` created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default after a clone, all refs are *packed* – stored in a single file `.git/packed-refs` for better performance. See [git pack-refs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-refs) for more details.

They will begin appearing as individual files under `.git/refs/` the moment they're first *updated* (e.g. by a future pull/fetch), but might get re-packed during git's occassional automatic maintenance.

Packed and unpacked refs behave 100% identically: they still exist in the local repository, they will show up in `git branch -r`, you can checkout them, and so on.